# Convert AnsibleUnsafeText to int

Tags: ansible

Let's say the df command return the following.

```
[john.doe@localhost ~]# df
Filesystem                           1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                               372607   170989    177862  50% /boot
/dev/sda2                               129774     6994    122780   6% /
```

With Ansible, I can use the shell module to capture the available value for /dev/sda1 (177862).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: df command
    shell: df | grep sda1 | awk '{print $4}'
    register: out

  - name: standard out
    debug:
      msg: "{{ out.stdout }}"

  - name: type
    debug:
      msg: "{{ out.stdout | type_debug }}"
```

Which will show the type is **AnsibleUnsafeText**. If I do the same with gather_facts, AnsibleUnsafeText is also returned. I can't figure out how to get the type to be an integer instead of AnsibleUnsafeText.

```
TASK [standard out] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "122780"
}

TASK [type] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "AnsibleUnsafeText"
}
```

I tried using the int filter.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: df command
    shell: df | grep sda1 | awk '{print $4}'
    register: out

  - name: int filter
    set_fact:
      foo: "{{ out.stdout | int }}"

  - name: type
    debug:
      msg: "{{ foo | type_debug }}"
```

But even with the int filter, the type remains AnsibleUnsafeText.

```
TASK [type] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "AnsibleUnsafeText"
}
```

The reason I want to the type to be int is so that I can compare integers, like this.

```yaml
- name: do something
  debug:
    msg: do something
  when: df_available > '123456'
```

Comment: related discussion https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30366

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This `"{{ out.stdout | int }}"` will cast `out.stdout` to an `int`, but as it is a template, it will then cast it back to `string`, as a template always returns a string.
That is just what templates do. They evaluate the template code and then generate text and return it.

If you want to use the variable to compare it as `int`, you need to cast it every time, you use it:

```yaml
- name: do something
  debug:
    msg: do something
  when: (df_available | int) > 123456
```

Comment: Great explanation on how template casting always returns a string and providing a perfect working example of how to apply int in a when statement. Works perfectly!