# Why is data type 'AnsibleUnsafeText' instead of dict?

Tags: ansible

I have a role that runs some SQL queries and I create a dictionary with the results. I've removed some logic in hopes to better understand. Even when setting static key and value I'm still getting `AnsibleUnsafeText`.

**ROLE**

```yaml
---
- name: Get Event Table Record Count
  command: <sql_command>
  register: record_count

- name: Get Event Tables oldest Record
  command: <sql_command>
  register: oldest_record

- name: Mapping Results
  set_fact:
    results: "{{ results|default({})|combine({'count': 5}) }}"
```

**PLAYBOOK**

```yaml
---

- name: Clean  Tables.
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true

  vars:
    event_tables:
      - table1
      - table2
      - table3

  tasks:
    - name: Get Event Table Count and Oldest Event Date
      include_role:
        name: get_count_and_latest_record
      with_items: "{{ event_tables }}"
      vars:
        - table: "{{ item }}"
        
    - debug: msg="{{ item | type_debug }}"
      with_items: "{{ event_tables }}"
```

I don't understand what specific text is unsafe?

`"msg": "AnsibleUnsafeText",`

Comment: ... I've the feeling that Ansible Data Types could be documentend more and better.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are [registering the result of a command in a variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables), Ansible can't know what will be the content which becomes delivered. Therefore the registered `Text` output is marked as `Unsafe`.

You can find further background information in [Unsafe or raw strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings).

> *When handling values returned by ... Ansible uses a data type called unsafe to block templating. Marking data as unsafe prevents malicious users from abusing Jinja2 templates to execute arbitrary code on target machines. The Ansible implementation ensures that unsafe values are never templated.*

**Further Information**

- [An introduction to Ansible facts](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/playing-ansible-facts)

  > ***Ansible Unsafe Text**: This type of variable doesn't have any subpart and stores the data directly*

Depending on what is stored within your `AnsibleUnsafeText` you would need to do a type casting for further processing.

**Further Q&A**

- [Convert `AnsibleUnsafeText` to `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676155/)
- [How to convert an `AnsibleUnsafeText` HEX value to `int`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992457/)